# How can I run python in terminal on a mac?

Tags: python, macos

I'm extremely new to programming, in fact I'm trying to learn Python now as a first language. I found that Google has a python course and it said to download python 2 from python's website, which I did, and I now realize that python was already installed on my mac by apple. Anyways, I also had to download some exercises from google, and attempt to run some code in terminal and this is where I'm running into trouble and could really use some insight.

First, the lesson said to simply type, `python`, into terminal to start coding in python (I don't know if this is the way to say that, or if that just gives you the ability to run python code?)

Then, it said to type in: `python hello.py`

Which was supposed to return: `Hello World`

However, all I keep getting is :

> SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax

And I don't really know where to go from here, I was thinking maybe it's due to me downloading python again when it was already installed, if it even was?

Comment: Are you in the same directory as hello.py? Also, you need to ensure Python is installed on your system.

Comment: typing python at the terminal invokes the python interpreter which lets you run python code.

Comment: @KyleBooth Could you explain what that means exactly?

Comment: Syntax error might mean there is a problem with your file hello.py please post its contents

Comment: Try print('Hello world') instead.

Comment: @DavidGreydanus thats probably it. He is following a python 2 tutorial but he is using python 3 interpreter

Comment: If you type 'pwd' you can see what directory you're currently in. If it's not the directory of the file, you need to use 'cd' to change your current directory.

Comment: @KyleBooth This is what I got back after typing 'pwd': Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pwd' is not defined

Comment: Because you're in Python now instead of Terminal :) I was under the impression you had written hello.py already and were trying to run the script in terminal. Nevermind!

Comment: @KyleBooth Ok so since I'm in python shouldn't hello.py work?

Comment: No. "python hello.py" is the command you would run from Terminal if you wanted to run the python script (while not actually in python).

Comment: @KyleBooth Ah ok I see thanks, also this is a very basic question but is there something better to use than terminal for running python code?

Comment: Yes, ideally you should use the Python shell.

Comment: @KyleBooth: You're in Terminal either way; the distinction is between being in the Python interpreter or being in the bash shell.

Comment: Terminal is a perfectly good way to run Python code. You need to learn the difference between the bash shell (which should have a prompt like `JaysMac:jay jay$`) and the Python interpreter (which should have a prompt like `>>>`) anyway, and once you learn that, the confusion will go away. However, there are all kinds of graphical IDEs for Python—IDLE, PyCharm, Eclipse PyDev, etc.—which you might find useful.

Comment: By the way, there are good reasons to have an extra Python separate from Apple's, and also good reasons to _not_ have two copies of Python around that will confuse you. But if you installed an extra one and aren't using it, you're getting the worst of both worlds, and you probably want to uninstall it.

Comment: @Jay please accept an answer or write your own if you think you already have an answer to your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First, the lesson said to simply type, python, into terminal to start coding in python (I don't know if this is the way to say that, or if that just gives you the ability to run python code?)

What happens when you type a program name into terminal is that it basically executes the program, and if it has a GUI, the GUI window will pop up onto the screen. If it only has a command-line interface (like `python`) the program will be executed inside the terminal.

In the case of running `python`, what it does is actually to load a python interpreter inside your terminal. If you notice, the command-line interface would have changed quite a bit (I am on Windows so I am not sure how it looks like exactly on Mac). So instead of something like

```
YourName@USER ~/Path/to/your/exercise/files
$ _
```

at the start of the line, you would have encountered the below instead:

```
# Bunch of text describing your python version and other things
>>> _
```

That is actually the python interpreter's command line. You can only execute python codes here.

> Then, it said to type in: `python hello.py`
>
> Which was supposed to return: `Hello World`
>
> However, all I keep getting is : `SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax`

I suspect when you are running the command `python hello.py`, you were still inside the python interpreter program, which is why it return the `InvalidSyntax` error, because it is not a valid python syntax.

What `python hello.py` does (if you were to run it in your terminal instead) is to execute the python interpreter, supplying your `hello.py` file as the code for the interpreter to interpret and execute. So it is as if you run `python` and entering the codes you wrote inside `hello.py` into the python interpreter. So,

> I was thinking maybe it's due to me downloading python again when it was already installed, if it even was?

nope, it was not. It was because of the reasons I explained above.

Hope it helps!

**Edit**

A little bit of extra info, to properly exit the python interpreter command line, you can type `exit()` or `quit()`. Ctrl+D works too, as a shortcut.

Comment: Can you run other programming languages in terminal besides python?

Comment: If you have the interpreter, then sure. For example, you can run JavaScript on node.js, ruby on rb (ruby's interpreter), etc. Note, you don't actually run the code inside the _terminal_, you are running the code inside the _interpreter_, which happens to be running inside your terminal. (I hope I don't confuse you haha)

Comment: It's neither Cmd+D nor Cmd+Z, it's Ctrl+D. Cmd shortcuts are generally for _GUI_ apps on Mac, Ctrl shortcuts for terminal apps. So, you can Cmd+Q to quit the Terminal completely, or Cmd+W to close the window, but Ctrl+D to quit Python while leaving the Terminal window alone.

Answer (score 3):

type python into terminal. It will display what version of python you have installed then you can begin by typing:

```
print("hello world!")
```

python = completed it mate

Answer (score 1):

`python` command will open a Python interpreter, where you can't run the `python hello.py` command so you got the syntax error (to run `hello.py` in python shell you need `execfile(hello.py)`) to quit the Python interpreter, type `ctrl+d` and than `python hello.py` to execute your hello world script.

Comment: Typing cmd+z at the terminal isn't going to do anything but beep. Maybe you meant ctrl-d?

Comment: I am refering to the ctrl+z in ubuntu

Comment: @WajdiFarhani  After doing ctrl+d and then python hello.py, I get this: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'hello.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Well, ctrl+z works on Mac just like on Ubuntu, but it's a bad idea in either case—that doesn't actually quit the Python interpreter, it just suspends it.

Comment: @Jay: That's a whole other problem, which Kyle Booth's comments about the current working directory may help you with. But really, I think you need to read a tutorial on basic Unix command-line stuff before going any further; there will be too many questions that are too hard to answer in isolation./

Comment: @Jay be sure that you are in the same directory as your python script

Comment: Alright thanks, I don't really know how to use the command-line so I need to brush up on that

Comment: But I did download the exercise directory from google that it said to download, so when it says 'No such file or directory' I'm kind of confused because i do have it

Comment: you really have it but in in other directory than where you are

Comment: @Jay try `find / -name 'hello.py' to get the directory where your script is stord (hope that you don't have more than one script with that name on your disk)

Comment: @WajdiFarhani It doesn't return anything just a space with the little indent >

Answer (score -2):

The first thing is that your file can't be named python hellow.py it should be named python_hellow.py.

And to run it:
On macOS: type: python python_hellow.py
On Windows: type: python3 python_hellow.py

Comment: The file can be named `hellow.py` and it sill run, unless there is an existing package with the same name.